# How to overwrite instance/form values in clean method of Django 2.0?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

How to overwrite instance/form values in a clean method of Django 2.0?

class LocationForm(forms.ModelForm):

```
def clean(self):
    # do some work
    if check_condition:
        raise ValidationError
    # pass validation checks
    # overwrite new field value
    instance.field = new_val
```

The overwritten field should be overwritten and take effect in the new model instance.

The reason I want to do this in the clean method is so that I can raise validation errors within the form.

Using a model's save method works, but raising a validation error does not render errors on the form in django template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overwrite the `clean` method and just update the `cleaned_data`.

```
def clean(self):
    self.cleaned_data = super().clean()
    self.cleaned_data['field'] = value
    return self.cleaned_data
```

You can also add form errors in here. like `self.add_error('field', 'error message')` which will raise the `ValidationError` for you and render the form with errors.

Comment: Note that this will only work if editable form fields were changed, else no changes are saved.